# Is it possible to allow only some client certificates in Apache to login?

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, ssl-certificate, certificate, mod-ssl

In my virtual host I have something like that:

```
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/svn.XXXXX.me.key
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/svn.XXXXX.me.crt
    SSLProtocol all
    SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM
    SSLVerifyClient require
    SSLCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/ICA-Standart.0
```

So far, I can use any certificate issued by CA "ICA-Standart.0" to log in, but I would like to specify kind of white list and only some certificates will be allowed to log in, is that possible?
If so, which directive should I look?

Also please note the CA is a public certification authority.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the `SSL_CLIENT_S_*` directives:

```
    Require              ssl
    Require              ssl-verify-client
    SSLRequireSSL
    SSLOptions           +FakeBasicAuth +StrictRequire
    SSLRequire           %{SSL_CIPHER_USEKEYSIZE} >= 256
    SSLRequire           %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_O} eq "Company, LTD." \
                         and %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_OU} eq "Development" \
                         and %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN} in {"John Doe", "Jane Doe", "Other One"}
    SSLRenegBufferSize   131072
```

Further reference can be found in the [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html) documentation.